# mecab-chをmakeする際に「`aclocal-1.10' is missing on your system.」のエラー

Tags: makefile

mecab-‌​0.996（日本語用）は既にインストールしていますが、[mecab-ch（中国語用）](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/99761e0af7tqp/mecab-ch)をインストールしたいです。

どのようにインストールするかわかる方いれば教えていただけるとありがたいです。  
下記のinstallのドキュメントに従ってインストールしましたが上手くいきません。

```
1. `cd' to the directory containing the package's source code and type
 `./configure' to configure the package for your system.  If you're
 using `csh' on an old version of System V, you might need to type
 `sh ./configure' instead to prevent `csh' from trying to execute
 `configure' itself.

 Running `configure' takes awhile.  While running, it prints some
 messages telling which features it is checking for.
2. Type `make' to compile the package.

3. Optionally, type `make check' to run any self-tests that come with
 the package.

4. Type `make install' to install the programs and any data files and
documentation.
```

makeの表示　エラーの内容

```
[root@localhost mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823]# make
cd . && /bin/sh /root/デスクトップ/mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823/missing --run aclocal-1.10 
/root/デスクトップ/mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823/missing: 行 52: aclocal-1.10: コマンドが見つかりません
WARNING: `aclocal-1.10' is missing on your system.  You should only need it if
     you modified `acinclude.m4' or `configure.in'.  You might want
     to install the `Automake' and `Perl' packages.  Grab them from
     any GNU archive site.
cd . && /bin/sh /root/デスクトップ/mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823/missing --run automake-1.10 --gnu 
/root/デスクトップ/mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823/missing: 行 52: automake-1.10: コマンドが見つかりません
WARNING: `automake-1.10' is missing on your system.  You should only need it if
     you modified `Makefile.am', `acinclude.m4' or `configure.in'.
     You might want to install the `Automake' and `Perl' packages.
     Grab them from any GNU archive site.
cd . && /bin/sh /root/デスクトップ/mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823/missing --run autoconf
/root/デスクトップ/mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823/missing: 行 52: autoconf: コマンドが見つかりません
WARNING: `autoconf' is missing on your system.  You should only need it if
     you modified `configure.in'.  You might want to install the
     `Autoconf' and `GNU m4' packages.  Grab them from any GNU
     archive site.
/bin/sh ./config.status --recheck
running CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/sh /bin/sh ./configure --no-create --no-recursion
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for mecab-config... /usr/bin/mecab-config
configure: creating ./config.status
/bin/sh ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
make: `all' に対して行うべき事はありません.
```

make installの表示

```
[root@localhost mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823]# make install
make[1]: ディレクトリ `/root/デスクトップ/mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823' に入ります
make[1]: `install-exec-am' に対して行うべき事はありません.
test -z "/usr/lib64/mecab/dic/naist-cdic" || /usr/bin/mkdir -p "/usr/lib64/mecab/dic/naist-cdic"
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 'matrix.bin' '/usr/lib64/mecab/dic/naist-cdic/matrix.bin'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 'char.bin' '/usr/lib64/mecab/dic/naist-cdic/char.bin'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 'sys.dic' '/usr/lib64/mecab/dic/naist-cdic/sys.dic'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 'unk.dic' '/usr/lib64/mecab/dic/naist-cdic/unk.dic'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 'left-id.def' '/usr/lib64/mecab/dic/naist-cdic/left-id.def'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 'right-id.def' '/usr/lib64/mecab/dic/naist-cdic/right-id.def'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 'rewrite.def' '/usr/lib64/mecab/dic/naist-cdic/rewrite.def'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 'pos-id.def' '/usr/lib64/mecab/dic/naist-cdic/pos-id.def'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 'dicrc' '/usr/lib64/mecab/dic/naist-cdic/dicrc'
make[1]: ディレクトリ `/root/デスクトップ/mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823' から出ます
```

[image: mecabのファイルについて]

Comment: 回答を得た後に質問を変更してしまうと既存の回答が的外れになってしまいます。変更するのではなく質問文に追記するか、新たに別の質問として投稿してください。

Comment: `'./README' not found` の件はその後[別質問](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/30983/8000)を投稿されたようなので、こちらは回答が投稿された頃の内容にロールバックしました。

Answer (score 0):

> WARNING: `aclocal-1.10' is missing on your system.  You should only need it if you modified`acinclude.m4' or `configure.in'.  You might want to install the`Automake' and `Perl' packages.  Grab them from any GNU archive site.

メッセージを見ると、automakeをインストールする必要があります。
automakeの[インストール方法](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278928/how-to-overcome-aclocal-1-15-is-missing-on-your-system-warning-when-compilin)はここを参照してください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。aclocal-1.10インストールしました。　Makefile.am: required file `./README' not foundのエラーが表示されます。

Comment: 「automake --add-missing」のようにREADMEを指定すれば解消できると思います。