# mecab-chをmakeする際に『Makefile.am: required file `./README' not found』と表示される

Tags: makefile

mecab-ch（中国語用）をインストールしたいです。

どのようにインストールするかわかる方いれば教えていただけるとありがたいです。

makeの表示　エラーの内容

```
[root@localhost mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823]# make 
cd . && /bin/sh /root/デスクトップ/mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823/missing --run automake-1.10 --gnu 
Useless use of /d modifier in transliteration operator at /usr/local/share/automake-1.10/Automake/Wrap.pm line 60.
Makefile.am: required file `./README' not found
make: *** [Makefile.in] エラー 1
```

makefile.am 変更後

```
[root@localhost mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823]# make
 cd . && /bin/sh /root/デスクトップ/mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823/missing --run automake-1.10 --gnu
Useless use of /d modifier in transliteration operator at /usr/local/share/automake-1.10/Automake/Wrap.pm line 60.
cd . && /bin/sh /root/デスクトップ/mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823/missing --run autoconf/bin/sh ./config.status --recheck
running CONFIG_SHELL=/bin/sh /bin/sh ./configure --no-create --no-recursion
```

[image: configureのドキュメント]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

GNUに準じていないことを宣言すれば解決できると思います。
Makefile.amに下記のオプションを追加してみてください。

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。　指示通りにやってみましたら、上記のメッセージが表示されます。　インストールされていないようです。

Answer (score 1):

```
luna:~/mecab % pwd
/home/masm/mecab
luna:~/mecab % ls
mecab-0.996.tar.gz  mecab-ch.tar.gz  mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801.tar.gz
luna:~/mecab %
```

この状態から、

```
mkdir src
cd src

tar zxf ../mecab-0.996.tar.gz
cd mecab-0.996
./configure --prefix=/home/masm/mecab
make
make check
make install
cd ..

tar zxf ../mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801.tar.gz
cd mecab-ipadic-2.7.0-20070801
./configure --prefix=/home/masm/mecab --with-mecab-config=/home/masm/mecab/bin/mecab-config
make
make install
echo dicrc = /home/masm/mecab/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic >> /home/masm/mecab/etc/mecabrc
cd ..

tar zxf ../mecab-ch.tar.gz
cd mecab-ch
touch aclocal.m4
touch Makefile.in configure
chmod a+x configure
./configure --prefix=/home/masm/mecab --with-mecab-config=/home/masm/mecab/bin/mecab-config
cp mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823/* ./
make clean
make
make install
echo dicrc = /home/masm/mecab/lib/mecab/dic/naist-cdic >> /home/masm/mecab/etc/mecabrc
```

以上で、

```
luna:~/mecab % ls -al /home/masm/mecab/lib/mecab/dic/naist-cdic
合計 8224
drwxr-xr-x 2 masm users    4096 12月 10 04:13 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 masm users    4096 12月 10 04:13 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 masm users  262496 12月 10 04:13 char.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 masm users     156 12月 10 04:13 dicrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 masm users     576 12月 10 04:13 left-id.def
-rw-r--r-- 1 masm users    4054 12月 10 04:13 matrix.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 masm users     472 12月 10 04:13 pos-id.def
-rw-r--r-- 1 masm users     153 12月 10 04:13 rewrite.def
-rw-r--r-- 1 masm users     576 12月 10 04:13 right-id.def
-rw-r--r-- 1 masm users 8114657 12月 10 04:13 sys.dic
-rw-r--r-- 1 masm users    4035 12月 10 04:13 unk.dic
luna:~/mecab %
```

このように、たぶんインストールできていると思います。
実行して試したわけではありませんけど。

automake, autoconf, aclocal が必要、という warning は、上記のように touch で解決することがあります。
それより、必要だったのは cp ではないかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。上記のようにやってみましたら、make: /mecab-dict-index: コマンドが見つかりませんでした
make: *** [matrix.bin] エラー 127というメッセージが表示されます。

Comment: @FannyZhingre `mecab-config --libexecdir` を実行すると、何が出力されますか? もし何も出力されないようでしたら、mecab のインストールからやり直した方が良いと思います。また「遠隔操作」というのは、私に代わりにやってくれ、ということでしょうか? でしたら、それはやる気はありません。

Comment: 実行すると[root@localhost mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823]# mecab-config --libexecdir
/usr/libexec/mecabのメッセージが表示されます。　よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @FannyZhingre 何故だろう…。対症療法として、mecab-ch の configure 実行後の Makefile 中、`MECAB_DICT_INDEX`, `mecab_dict_index` の2つの変数に `/mecab-dict-index` と設定されていると思いますので、両方を `/usr/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-index` に書き換えて、configure せずに make だけしてみてください。

Comment: configureのドキュメント（上記の写真）の/mecab-dict-indexを/usr/libexec/mecab/mecab-dict-indexに変更後、上記ののメッセージが表示されます。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: @FannyZhingre 以上でインストール完了だと思うのですが…

Comment: まだインストールされていないようです。mecab-0.996とmecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823を比べるとmecab-0.996の方がconfig.sub ,install-shに色が付いています。（上記の写真）

Comment: @FannyZhingre インストールの結果として期待していることが、私と Fanny Zhingre さんとで異なっているように思えます。`/usr/lib64/mecab/dic/naist-cdic/` にいくつかファイルが作成されていませんか?

Comment: 度々すいません。作成されています。動作確認の仕方が分からないので、どのように動作すればか。分かりますか。

Comment: 日本語 辞書のmecabの場合、コマンドでmecabを入力するだけ動作確認できます。mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-201208‌​23の場合、違うかもしれません。

Comment: 下記のﾒﾂセージには、上記の写真にもありますが動作確認と関係していると思いますか。

Comment: done!
echo To enable dictionary, rewrite /mecabrc as \"dicrc = /naist-cdic\"
To enable dictionary, rewrite /mecabrc as "dicrc = /naist-cdic"
[root@localhost mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823]# make install
make[1]: ディレクトリ `/root/デスクトップ/mecab-naist-cdic-1.1.1-20120823' に入ります
make[1]: `install-exec-am' に対して行うべき事はありません.
test -z "/naist-cdic" || /usr/bin/mkdir -p "/naist-cdic"

Comment: @FannyZhingre  申し訳ありませんが、私が解るのは make に関する問題までで、mecab や mecab-naist-cdic については解りません。ですので、私はここまでとさせていただきます。健闘を祈ります。

Comment: 色々とありがとうございました。